# How to do a select from table where values in a pandas series?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, google-bigquery

For example:

```
>>> df['id']
>>> 1   2324
    2   4323
    3   4321
    4   1232
    n   ....
...
>>> query = client.query('''
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE id IN (df['id']) 

''').to_dataframe()
```

what is the right way to call my pandas series? it is possible?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should dynamically build the `IN` part of your SQL statement and produce `(2324, 4323...)` and append it to your SQL statement.

If your DataFrame contains too many values, you could create a temporary table on the SQL server side, insert the values from your DataFrame into that temp table, then do a regular join.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `join` to create a id list and f-string to insert that list into the query:

```
all_ids = df['id'].astype(str).agg(','.join)
query = client.query(f'''
SELECT *
  FROM my_table
 WHERE id IN ({all_ids})
''').to_dataframe()
```